# Flutter: update stateful widget from child StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have written some simplified code where I want the condition of firestore data to be able to update a parent widget.

I get the error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

How can I update the state of myVar from inside StreamBuilder? After updating myVar the StreamBuilder will not be accessed, instead only the text Waiting... should be displayed.

Edit: I updated myVar to be used as the document ID of Firestore. To clarify, I want to be able to update the document of the StreamBuilder from inside the StreamBuilder. In other words as the question says, update stateful widget from child StreamBuilder.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget({Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() {
    return _MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String myVar = "someID";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (myVar == null) {
      // update myVar async, so that StreamBuilder will be re-rendered
      asyncFunctUpdate(myVar); // edit: finally got it to work if doing setState from asyncFuncUpdate(myvar).then(()=>setState)
      return Text("Waiting...");
    }
    else
      return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection('myCollection')
              .document(myVar)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, orderSnapshot) {
            if (!orderSnapshot.data.exists)
              setState(() {
                myVar = null;
              });
            else return Text(orderSnapshot);
          });
  }
}
```

Workaround:
In my case it was simpler to just return buttons from the StreamBuilder and setState as normally from onPressed functions.

Solution:
Instead of doing setState from an async function do it within the .then clause (see code above)

Comment: You should create an ```async``` method and call it from stream builder. Something like: ```void setMyVar(String var) async { setState(() { myVar = var})```. This should run after the build is done.

Comment: @danypata Calling a function that uses the async keyword even if it doesn't need it will not change anything about the way that function is executed - it will still be executed synchronously, before `build` completes. As for the actual solution, check Artem's answer.

Comment: It's true that making the call async doesn't work. It returns the same error.

I updated the code because it didn't portray my question clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not have to do what you are doing now. You can do return Text ("Waiting ..."); right away without calling setState. This is a better decision in your case. You respond to events coming from the stream and must return content according to the current state

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('myCollection')
          .document('myDocument')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, orderSnapshot) {
        if (!orderSnapshot.data.exists)
            return Text("Waiting...");
        else return Text(orderSnapshot);
      });
```

Comment: Hey Artem, I wasn't clear enough in my simplified code, but in the real code there is a variable myDocument which should change in the event where "Waiting..." is displayed. I didn't want StreamBuilder to be "accessed", in other words rendered. Sorry that I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the update async like putting it inside an anonymous async callback like

```
() async {
    setState();
}();
```

OR

You can avoid having state in that particular use case like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('myCollection')
          .document('myDocument')
          .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, orderSnapshot) {
          if (!orderSnapshot.data.exists) {
            return Text("Waiting...");
          } else {
            return Text(orderSnapshot);
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I had to update my question since this answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: With further investigation it seems that it worked to do setState from the .then clause rather than inside the async function